# issue with wrapping a array of signs with ^ sign

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a function to wrap an array of signs with `^` sign, and it works fine for `string1`, let's have a look:

```js
function modifyAuto(string) {
    const allSigns = ['!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', '،', '؛', ','];
    const str = allSigns.map(e => e.replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\./g, '\\.')).join('|');
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\s*(?:\\^\\s*)*(${str})\\s*(?:\\^\\s*)*`, 'g');
    return string.replace(regex, ' ^$1^ ');
}

const string1 = 'this is a text, right';
const string2 = 'this is a text, ^right^';

console.log('works fine :::', modifyAuto(string1)) 
console.log('one of the ^ signs removed :::', modifyAuto(string2))
```

as you see for a normal `string1` the function works fine, **but as you see in `string2` if there is already a word wrapped with `^` close to a `,` sign for instance , one of the `^` will be removed.**

the desired result for the `string2` should be :

```
"this is a text ^,^ ^right^"
```

How would you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then only remove `^`s that are immediately before/after the found match with

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`\\s*\\^?(${str})\\^?\\s*`, 'g');
```

See the fixed demo:

```js
function modifyAuto(string) {
    const allSigns = ['!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', '،', '؛', ','];
    const str = allSigns.map(e => e.replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\./g, '\\.')).join('|');
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\s*\\^?(${str})\\^?\\s*`, 'g');
    return string.replace(regex, ' ^$1^ ');
}

const string1 = 'this is a text, right';
const string2 = 'this is a text, ^right^';

console.log('works fine :::', modifyAuto(string1)) 
console.log('one of the ^ signs removed :::', modifyAuto(string2))
```